How would a small, de-facto independent and ungoverned city obtain basic municipal services?
This is a follow-on from my question here:
A real-world large nation-state endures a long period of civil chaos in the near future. By the time this ends the state is controlled by two rival factions. There is a fragile state of peace between them. However, due to an ambiguous treaty a small-ish piece of land several square km in size was not allocated to either side and a more or less ungoverned neutral city grew up on that land.
It's very densely populated. They will need basic utilities such as water and electricity at the least, which will need to come from one or both of the rival factions. They can afford to pay some sort of nominal fee, but not build pipelines or large infrastructure to deliver it. Only the rival factions have the capability to do that.
Why would their neighbours be motivated to help them in this way, given that they don't pay taxes and aren't loyal citizens, and they risk losing any infrastructure they do build to the other faction?
EDIT:
As part of the backdrop of my world I want this scenario to be plausible and having reference to existing real-world scenarios. Therefore, answers that fail to reference real-world settlements where similar arrangements have come into being and explain the reasons for it are unacceptable.
The city I have in mind is somewhat similar to Kowloon Walled City but it is larger and not an enclave. KWC had access to electricity, water and sanitation from Hong Kong. In some cases this was through illegal connections but the HK administration also had an incentive to prevent it from becoming a humanitarian disaster which they would then have had to deal with so there were some water standpipes and a sewage line.
The challenge for me is to imagine a way this arrangement could "scale up", given that the city doesn't have close proximity to existing water and sewer lines and electrical infrastructure, and the political context is somewhat different.

Questions about the motivations or actions of characters (or states) are off-topic here as they are liable to generate opinion-based answers.

Why isn't this answered by the other question? As long as both sides are happy with the status quo, why wouldn't they trade, as long as the city can pay? If the city is so poor that it can't pay, why are so many people moving there?

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. As is stated in the [help/on-topic], questions about the motivations, decisions, actions, etc. of individuals and/or organizations is prohibited. This is because these are 100% storybuilding (on that same Help Center page it also states we help you build your world, not tell your story). It's possible to avoid this problem if you clearly explain how you're going to objectively select a best answer - elevating this above a prohibited brainstorming question.

There are a number of such communities - even here in the US along the southern border. A bit of research into how those communities function would answer the question.

I've voted to reopen after making a mandatory edit. The rules of stack exchange demand specificity and clarity. You stated an "ideal answer," leaving open the possibility of other answers. No can do. If you remove my edit, I'll retract my reopen vote. Bear in mind that Stack Exchange is NOT a free research service and there isn't a way to convert this into a worldbuilding process example because it's nothing more than pure research - so I've given you a gift. Please be sure you learn from it.

They become a version of 20th Century Switzerland or Lichtenstein
I.E. they become 'useful'. An independent city state that cannot even remotely threaten it's two competing neihbours militarily, economically or politically. BUT can still serve very nicely as a place where political and business 'deals' can be done, (openly or in private). A place where money can be stashed and/or transferred discretely. A place where disgraced, inconvenient or embarrassing politicians and others are allowed to go into exile (provided they agree to stay 'schtum' of course) on the understanding that they can never return until otherwise permitted.
In short it's a hot bed of political intrigue, espionage and money laundering. BUT, in doing so it serves a valuable purpose to both major powers whose political and economic leaders also need a place where their own 'dirty little secrets' and money can be stored away securely in the event they ever need a bolt hole.
And in return? The city state in question gets to import all the necessities of life it can't produce itself. All the while remaining publicly and stoically neutral because, after all who wants to ruin a good thing?

Or perhaps a Singapore?

@Jeff Zeitlin Yep, but then Singapore also has geography on it's side which makes it a important trade hub in it's own right so the banking and fiance sectors aren't necessarily as important to it as they are to other micro nations you could list.

If a town is unable to obtain the municipal services then it always has the option to not obtain these services at all, i.e. to become a slum. This doesn't necessarily mean that there are no services; there most likely will be some, but they would be DIY-ed by the local population as best they can, rather than provided by some central authority. In most of the populated world, drinking water falls from the sky completely free of charge, you only need a bucket to capture it. You can produce some electricity some of the time with a solar panel, if you have money to buy it, which you will: the town's population represents a pool of cheap labor which the businesses in the neighboring countries would be happy to hire, thus providing it with cash that it can then spend on things which cannot be produced locally. It will be rough going at first but after a few years, the town has every chance to no longer need basic services from its neighbors.

They might become loyal citizens if you pay for their infrastructure.
Usually contested territories are claimed by both sides at the same time - cases like Bir Tawil where neither side makes a claim to an area are rare. In your situation there's an entire (valuable) city and all its citizens there, and states would want a claim on that!
So each side maintains the legal fiction that the city belongs to them alone, and they are only not collecting taxes or passing laws because of logistical difficulties caused by Their Brutish Militia interfering with the duties of Our Hardworking Police.
"If we set up a system where they can pay us for water," the rival states reason "they'll also be able to use that system to pay their taxes. Naturally we'll forgive the twenty years of back taxes that the city has been unable to pay due to Extenuating Circumstances. Probably. After all, they are technically our citizens, even if they don't act like it yet. We just need to enforce a little order."
